# Simple problem with convergence in distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let ${\displaystyle X_{n}\ {\xrightarrow {\overset {}{d}}}\ a\quad}$, where a is constant.

Is that true that  $P(X_n<a) \rightarrow 0$ ?

My intuition tell's me that this is true so i tried to prove it

I tried to do something like this :

$P(X_n<a)=1-P(X_n=a)-P(X_n>a)$

And I stuck at this moment.

Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: No, it's not true. Consider e.g. $X_n := a-1/n$, then $X_n \to a$ almost surely (and hence in distribution) and $P(X_n<a)=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @saz That should be an answer, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_n\sim N(0,1/n)$. Then $X_n\stackrel{d}\to 0$, but $P(X_n<0)=\frac12\not\to 0$.